# images loading very slowly for ipad,tablets and mobiles with json?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, json

```
var customers = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Title1",
        "image_path": [
            "resources/images/cloud.png",
            "resources/images/cloud1.png"
        ],
        "content_path": "resources/json_html/customers/loud.html"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Title2",
        "image_path": [
            "resources/images/onpremise.png",
            "resources/images/onpremise1.png"
        ],
        "content_path": "resources/json_html/customers/onremise.html"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Title3",
        "image_path": [
            "resources/images/privatecloud.png",
            "resources/images/privatecloud1.png"
        ],
        "content_path": "resources/json_html/customers/private.html"
    },
];
```

```js
function showcustomerscontent(contentId) {
    var oldsrc = customers[jsonOldContentId - 1].image_path[0];
    var imagehtmlold = '<img src=' + oldsrc + ' id="image_opacity" class="img-responsive">';
    var idold = "imageId_" + [jsonOldContentId];

    document.getElementById(idold).innerHTML = imagehtmlold;

    var src = customers[contentId - 1].image_path[0];
    var newsrc = customers[contentId - 1].image_path[1];
    var src = newsrc;
    var imagehtml = '<img src=' + src + ' id="image_opacity" class="img-responsive">';
    var id = "imageId_" + [contentId];

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = imagehtml;

}
```

The problem here is in my page I have 3 small round icons at the top and when a user clicks an icon the content must load according to the icon clicked by the user. Also the clicked icon must change to some other icon.

In my code I am loading the images using JSON as you can see above in my code. So when I click any icon the second icon is loading very slowly - it takes a lot of time to load on mobiles, iPads, tablets. I even compressed the size of the icons but still it is taking time to load. So can anyone show me the right direction for this?

Comment: What exactly is slow, do you load the JSON async, or do you load it directly? Or is it the images itself which takes time - do you have url to look at?

Comment: @axel.michel yes images itself take time to load...

Comment: this is not a clear question as there may be many reasons for slow loading please provide a fiddle.

Comment: @User2413 do you mean it takes one second ( flicker ) to load ? there are 6 icons though not 3.

Comment: @ProllyGeek no it is taking lot of time like 4 to 5 seconds some times and it is also getting struck some times..i had tested it in iphone 6 plus..

Comment: @User2413 works perfect for me !

Comment: Best guess - make a sprite image containing all your icons and click states, onclick just modify position. In case this is not possible (because of responsive images) write all images directly, hide on state via CSS and modify this when clicking.

Comment: @axel.michel this is a good approach commonly used , but i think his issue is different.

Comment: @axel.michel  Guys is there any simple way to load images quickly??

Comment: I put together a fiddle to demonstrate a sprite based solution - that would be the best way to avoid any kind of flickering and you'll save a lot of http requests: http://jsfiddle.net/x4g86wdz/

Answer (score 0):

To comment the discussion above: the loading speed of image resources depends on many factors. But most important are connection speed and the hardware / client you'll use - so a simple way to speed up loading does not exists. 
One way to avoid flickering is loading all of your images directly - which will definitely increase the overall loading time on the other hand. As I suggested in the comment above, I would go for a sprite based solution. The [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/x4g86wdz/) shows a responsive sprite solution which might fit:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab">
        <a href="#url1" id="t1">
            <img class="spacer" src="{placeholder required  to handle responsiveness}" />
            <img src="{the sprite itself}" />
        </a>
    </li>
    [...]
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* wraps spacer and sprite image */
.tab a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 160px; /* your max icon size */
    width: 100%;    

}

.tab a img {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

.tab .spacer {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}

.tab a img + img {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: 100%;
}


/* positioning of the sprite elements */
#Id img {
    left: -400%;
}
```

Finally you'll simply need to toggle a CSS class when clicking on the link/ icon. See the fiddle for a working demo.

Comment: In the above fiddle only the clicked icon must be changed and remaining must be the default one(default image)..but as we can see in the fiddle ,whichever image we are clicking it is changing and all the images have been changed atlast..

Comment: @User2413 It is a demonstration how to work with a responsive sprite not a complete copy of your code. You asked for a way to optimize image loading, the fiddle was created to demonstrate that. But I updated the fiddle to fulfill your request (if I got it right) http://jsfiddle.net/x4g86wdz/1/